# Handling trailing slashes in connect-history-api-fallback and Express

Tags: express, react-router, single-page-application

I'm using `connect-history-api-fallback` to handle calls to routes("pages") handled by React Router in a React SPA. It's working great, except that any React Router "page" that's entered with a trailing slash fails.

`https://my.app/signup` - works.
`https://my.app/signup/` - fails.

Normally, Express will handle a trailing slash and just serve the url without it (so, you enter `https://my.app/signup/`, Express gives you `https://my.app/signup`). This is the behavior of other routes not using the history-connect middleware in the same app, and it's the behavior I'd like here, as well.

The only thing I could think of was to pass in rewrites to handle the trailing slash:

```js
import history from 'connect-api-history-fallback';

// ...setup 

app.use(
  history({
    rewrites: [
      {from: /\/signup\//, to:'/signup'}
    ]
  }),
  express.static(path.join(dirname, 'some/directory'))
);
```

However, this fails.

And it doesn't even make it to my React app (unlike just calling a route that doesn't exist, like `https://my.app/fakeroute`, which loads the app with no content), so it's not an issue of the routes within React.

Does anyone know the correct way to do this? As a popular module, I can't imagine it can't handle trailing slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you're running the latest version of `connect-history-api-fallback`.  I just tested it and it's working correctly with `/signup` and `/signup/`

```
const express = require('express');
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

const app = express();

app.use(
    history({
        rewrites: [
            { from: /\/signup/, to: '/signup'}
        ]
    })
)

app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
    res.send("signup");
})

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @MattB! In my app, `/signup` is actually a React Router Route; so there isn't an express route that corresponds to it. The `connect-history-api-fallback` handles navigation to these, successfully; except when there's a trailing slash. So I don't think this solution would apply.